# RunTimeError in Twint : This event loop is already running

Tags: python

I use a jupyter notebook and run twint.

Code

```
c = twint.Config()
c.Username = 'twitter'
c.Limit = 20
twint.run.Followers(c)
```

The above commands produce a runtime error relating to (I believe) the code attempting to create 2 asynchronous event loops.
Traceback as follows:

```
RuntimeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4713cc05fb59> in <module>()
----> 1 twint.run.Favorites(c)

~/coding/tools/twint/twint/run.py in Favorites(config)
    119 def Favorites(config):
    120     config.Favorites = True
--> 121     run(config)
    122 
    123 def Followers(config):

~/coding/tools/twint/twint/run.py in run(config)
    115 
    116 def run(config):
--> 117     get_event_loop().run_until_complete(Twint(config).main())
    118 
    119 def Favorites(config):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py in run_until_complete(self, future)
    453         future.add_done_callback(_run_until_complete_cb)
    454         try:
--> 455             self.run_forever()
    456         except:
    457             if new_task and future.done() and not future.cancelled():

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py in run_forever(self)
    407         self._check_closed()
    408         if self.is_running():
--> 409             raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
    410         if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
    411             raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Answer (score 23):

I have found a solution for Jupyter notebooks
using the nest_async

Simply do

```
pip install nest_asyncio
```

And add these lines.

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Comment: I ran these lines and I keep getting this message: CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noDataExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sleeping for 64.0 secs.  The # of seconds keeps increasing.